# FirebaseFunctionsException: code: -1007, too many HTTP redirects

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. It happens either on a virtual or real device. I try to uninstall the app and nothing change. Why a simple helloWord function throw this error. I have no console log displayed. In the log I have this message: "Request has invalid method. GET" then "Error: Invalid request, unable to process. at entryFromArgs..." Why redirect? Could it be related to the cloud region I change? How could I clean that. Thank you.

Below the cloud function.

```
exports.belleDiana = functions.region(CLOUD_REGION).https.onCall(async (data, context) : Promise<String> => {
    console.log("belleDiana", data, context);
    console.log("context.auth", context.auth?.uid, context);
    return "belleDianaDone";
});
```

The call on flutter side.

```
    try {
      final result =
      await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('belleDiana').call();
      print("result: $result");
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      print(error);
      print(error.code);
      print(error.details);
      print(error.message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I switch to the original region 'us-central1'. When I change cloud region I have this message " Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/myproject/europe-west1/gcf-artifacts
"

After the deletion of that manually, every thing work as attended. I don't really understand why...